# Is there a way to debug which dependency causes a custom Knockout binding's update function to be called?

Tags: javascript, debugging, knockout.js

Is there a (relatively) easy way to debug which dependency causes the update callback of a [custom Knockout binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) to be called? My problem is that a binding is receiving updates repeatedly, and I can't see what is triggering these updates. I'm thinking there's an implicit dependency of the binding that is changing, but I can't see how to pinpoint it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to track down the observable responsible for the updates, through the process of elimination, i.e. disabling parts of the update callback at a time until I eventually found a mutating call to an observable that caused updates. I'd still like to know if there's a smarter/more direct debugging method though :)